# How to get the list of online users on Live Messenger through PHP?

Tags: php, instant-messaging, windows-live-messenger

Is it possible to get a list of connected users on msn throw php without using an additional application running on the server?

Basically I don't use msn but sometimes I need to talk with somebody and I need to know when he/she get online to talk and I would like to leave a cron that checks if that person is online. (sometimes I'm not at the computer but if I receive a mail I can try to get one)

Thanks for any response :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a class that can do it.](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2299-PHP-Grab-the-list-of-contacts-of-a-MSN-Messenger-user.html)

Comment: I will take it a try on the weekend :D if it works I will mark the answer button, thanks alex